# Windows Subsystem for Linux ignores metadata option while mounting

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have two disks - SSD(NTFS) with the windows and HDD(NTFS) with the large project. I need to change some ownerships of some directories there. But it's not working.

I was trying to remount disk D: in a next way to use drvfs with the metadata.

> sudo mount -t drvfs D: /mnt/d -o metadata,uid=1001,gid=1001,umask=22,fmask=111

But **mount -l** still says it's not using metadata for D:, and it's properly works with C:.

```
rootfs on / type lxfs (rw,noatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime)
none on /dev type tmpfs (rw,noatime,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,noatime,gid=5,mode=620)
none on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,noatime,mode=755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,mode=755)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noatime)
C: on /mnt/c type drvfs (rw,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=22,fmask=111,metadata)
D: on /mnt/d type drvfs (rw,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000)
```

Problem is:

> How to mount disk (not system C) with the metadata enabled to be able to use **chown and chmod**.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. But a reboot didn't help. I also tried to mount with domain name instead of drive letter. Same thing. 
Does anyone else have a solution for this?

Comment: I have the same issue with NTFS fileshare: metadata option ignored for both chmod and fstab, when checking with findmnt. Hence stuck with 555 subdirs where I can't create files.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Windows =) Reboot fixed the problem, but now all disks needs to be mounted manually. =(